Can an Azure SAML application be setup such that users not in the AD can login with their Username and Password instead of the SSO login flow?
I have an Azure SAML web application. On the Single sign-on (SSO) page, users enter their credentials (set in Azure Active Directory) to sign in.
Can an option be given to users who are not in the Active Directory to bypass the SSO process? i.e. sign in using their application username and password on the application Login page while SSO users can click on a 'Sign-in with SSO' button on the Login page to go through the SSO process?
To bypass the application's Login page from the authentication process, I added few lines in the web.config. When I hit the application URL, the Login page is displayed however after entering the username, password and clicking on Login, the SSO page is displayed.
All pages are protected by the SSO. In this case how do we get non-AD users to sign in while SSO users go through the SSO process?

To enable non-AD users to bypass the SSO process while allowing SSO users to sign in seamlessly, you need to implement conditional authentication logic. Use separate authentication routes for non-AD users and SSO users. For non-AD users, provide a traditional login form, while SSO users can proceed with the SSO process triggered by the "Sign-in with SSO" button.
